# Mutual information of independent fair binary random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Let random variables $X,Y$ independent fair random variables that take the values 0 and 1 with equal probability and $Z=X+Y$. So, $I(X;Y)=0$ and I am trying to find their conditional mutual information:

\begin{eqnarray*}
I(X;Y|Z)&=&H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z)\\  
&=&H(X|Z)\\
&=&P(Z=1)H(X|Z=1)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}bit
\end{eqnarray*}

I cannot understand how we get to the second line i.e. why $H(X|Y,Z)=0$ and why we don't use joint PMF in the third line.

Comment: For second line: There's no uncertainty in $X$ given $Y$ and $Z$ since $Z=X+Y$. I don't think your third equality is correct.

Comment: @Ashok I understand that there is no uncertainty but I am trying to find a mathematical proof maybe by exploiting some property.

Comment: $H(X)-H(X|Y,Z)=I(X;Y,Z)=I(X;Y,X+Y)=I(X;X)=H(X)$. Hence, $H(X|Y,Z)=0$.